# Golang GORM scan to map

Tags: go, go-gorm

I do some query on my GORM application and right now for scanning row from database is using struct. But the problem is come when I need to do some query that different each other, which I need to create another struct for each query I have.

And actually I don't care about the data that I got from database, it just forwarded to client. So, for me making struct for each of it will be a lot of work. So I am thinking that if I can scan it to map[string]interface{} or []map[string]interface{}. So is it possible to do it on GORM?

And I also thinking about another thing is when column converted to interface{} what about date? It will be converted to string? (and also for other type like int, long, array, etc)

Comment: (disclaimer, I am a newbie to go). I haven't used Gorm, with github.com/jmoiron/sqlx I can do that using rows.MapScan( mymap ) where mymap is map[string]interface{}. I get dates as time.Time and integers as integers, chars with space padded strings, varchars as trimmed strings, binary data as hex encoded string etc.

Comment: Let me check about it

Answer (score 0):

Since [v0.2.0](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/commit/b0e1bccf4ad5f803df27a8974491bcbc04a4b02c) gorm [supports](https://gorm.io/docs/advanced_query.html#Find-To-Map) scanning to `map[string]interface{}` and `[]map[string]interface{}`:

```golang
result := map[string]interface{}{}
db.Model(&User{}).First(&result, "id = ?", 1)

var results []map[string]interface{}
db.Table("users").Find(&results)
```

As for the values, SQL driver from the standard library [returns](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.19.2/src/database/sql/driver/driver.go#L46) following types:

```golang
int64
float64
bool
[]byte
string
time.Time
```